# DocumentClient return a Single Object in Azure-CosmosDB

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

How can I change my method to return only one object of type `Cliente`?

My method:

```
public IQueryable <Cliente> GetByEmailCpf(string email, string cpf, string colletionId) 
{
  FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions {
   MaxItemCount = -1
  };

  IQueryable <Cliente> cliente = client.CreateDocumentQuery <Cliente> (
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, colletionId), queryOptions)
   .Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Cpf == cpf);

  return cliente;
}
```

> DocumentQueryException: Query expression is invalid, expression
>   https://127.0.0.1:8081/dbs/Comosos/colls/Cliente.Where(x => ((x.Email
>   == value(LR.Mobile.Data.Repositories.ModuloProduto.Classes.ClienteRepository+<>c__DisplayClass5_0).email)
>   OrElse (x.Cpf ==
>   value(LR.Mobile.Data.Repositories.ModuloProduto.Classes.ClienteRepository+<>c__DisplayClass5_0).cpf))).FirstOrDefault()
>   is unsupported. Supported expressions are 'Queryable.Where',
>   'Queryable.Select' & 'Queryable.SelectMany'

Comment: what mjwills said. Your method is returning a list instead of just a value. I'm curious though, do you need it to return each value? If so you'll need a loop to accomplish that either inside the method or at the point of call.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() is not supported without listing the results first somehow.

Comment: use this `Cliente cliente = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Cliente>(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, colletionId), queryOptions)
   .Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Cpf == cpf).ToList().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: and your method return type must be `Cliente` instead of `IQueryable <Cliente>`

Answer (score 3):

As described by your error, it appears you were attempting to use `FirstOrDefault`. This is currently not supported, and according to the Azure Cosmos feedback site, is currently not a priority:

[Add support for single entity retrieval instead of IEnumerable](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6771773-add-support-for-single-entity-retrieval-instead-of)

In that post, Microsoft recommends the following workaround:

> Instead we recommend you use Take(1).AsEnumerable() and then .First() or .Single() or .FirstOrDefault() for Single() and First(). Take(1) is translated to SELECT TOP 1 and is processed server-side so more efficient than the previous suggestion and is what you are trying to achieve.

By including the `Take(1)` statement, only the first result will be loaded into memory instead of the entire result of the where clause.

In your code, that would translate to something like the following:

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Cliente>(
               UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, colletionId), queryOptions)
             .Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Cpf == cpf)
             .Take(1)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

As others have mentioned, don't forget update your return type to `Cliente` as well.

Comment: This worked for me.  I take it that there is no async CreateDocumentQuery method?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do something like this:

```
public Cliente GetByEmailCpf(string email, string cpf, string colletionId) {
  FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions {
   MaxItemCount = -1
  };

  IQueryable <Cliente> cliente = client.CreateDocumentQuery <Cliente> (
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, colletionId), queryOptions)
   .Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Cpf == cpf).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

  return cliente;
 }
```

However in bigger collections this is not recommended. You are recommended to page your results with async.

```
public async Task<Cliente> GetByEmailCpf(string email, string cpf, string colletionId) {
  FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions {
   MaxItemCount = -1
  };

  var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery <Cliente> (
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, colletionId), queryOptions)
   .Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Cpf == cpf).AsDocumentQuery();

  while (query.HasMoreResults)
  {
      var items = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Cliente>();
      if(items.Count > 0)
          return items.FirstOrDefault();
  }

  return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve only single document from your collection then you need to change your method return type to `Cliente` instead of `IQueryable <Cliente>`.

```
public Cliente GetByEmailCpf(string email, string cpf, string colletionId)
{
    FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions
    {
        MaxItemCount = -1,
        EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
    };

    var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Cliente>(
              UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, colletionId), queryOptions)
             .Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Cpf == cpf);

    //If your collection have more than one document of specific email and cpf then
    Cliente cliente = query.ToList().FirstOrDefault();

    //If your collection have only single document of specific email and cpf then
    Cliente cliente = query.ToList().SingleOrDefault();


    return cliente;
}
```

Try once may it help you.

Comment: @cura, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: Solution worked for me. had to add "EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true" on feed options to get it working

Comment: @NoloMokgosi, thanks and answer updated with your changes

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this Extension:

```
public static T TakeOne<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    var documentQuery = source.AsDocumentQuery();            
    if (documentQuery.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var queryResult = documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>().Result;
        if (queryResult.Any())
        {
            return queryResult.Single<T>();
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
Cliente cliente = client.CreateDocumentQuery <Cliente> (
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, colletionId), queryOptions)
   .Where(x => x.Email == email || x.Cpf == cpf).TakeOne();
```